# How to add a property to each object element of an array in Typescript dynamically?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have an array of objects which is passed from a parent component and I would like to add a new boolean property to each of the objects on Child Component Initiation. So far I have tried:

```
this.selectedItems.map((item) => {
    return { ...item, newProperty: false };
});
```

I also tried it using `forEach` method instead of `map`.

It adds the property while I am inside of the `map` or `forEach` methods but it does not save the changes.

How can I save the changes or is there any other way I can achieve this?

Comment: `this.selectedItems = this.selectedItems.map(...)`? Or if you want to change the original objects, *don't* explicitly create new ones.

Comment: If I use this I get an error `Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'any[]'`

Comment: Use which? Give a [mre].

Comment: If I use `this.selectedItems = this.selectedItems.map(...)`

Comment: Then give a [mre]. [Edit] the question. You are including the callback too, right?

Comment: My bad. I included the callback but I was using `forEach` instead of `map`. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`map` does not modify the array. Instead it returns a new array that is the result of your map operation.

So all you need to do is capture the result.

```
const itemsWithNewProperty = this.selectedItems.map((item) => {
    return { ...item, newProperty: false };
});
```

Comment: why not use forEach?

Answer (score 2):

why not use forEach?

```
this.selectedItems.forEach((item) => {
    item.newProperty=false
});
```